# Display a changeable ListView next to a Webview

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android

I need to display a ListView next to a Webview (like the Master/Detail sample), but I need to be able to sort the ListView in a different order (to display some items by category or by name for example), but I did not succeed to make it possible with tabs, dropdown menu or SectionPagerAdapter because the Master/Detail sample uses Fragment, and the TabHost is not a Fragment. I am a bit lost with what I should use.

To make it clear, I want to display it like that :
[1](http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/070/Purple/v4/c7/85/51/c7855198-7fdc-399c-27a2-5d719ffeeca3/mzl.bvwrilhv.480x480-75.jpg)

Is there some open source project that use this kind of view, or do your have some advice to perform that ?

Comment: Have you tried [slindingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)?

Comment: yes but it is not really what I want to do. I just want a simple switch to change the list order, the two listview does not have to be shown at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it also manually. Just make two list views on top of each other and change their visibilities so only one at a time will be shown.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is just skeleton of you're UI that you can use.